# How can I search for an item within a cell that's also in a range?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have **Table A**:

```
╔═══╦═════╦═════════════╦══════════════════╗
║   ║  a  ║      b      ║         c        ║
╠═══╬═════╬═════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ 1 ║ ID  ║ LIST VALUES ║ Table B Values   ║
╠═══╬═════╬═════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ 2 ║ 123 ║ 231,583     ║ eggs,bacon       ║
╠═══╬═════╬═════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ 3 ║ 789 ║ 518,732     ║ bacon,bread      ║
╠═══╬═════╬═════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ 4 ║ 101 ║ 55,38       ║ tomato,onion     ║
╠═══╬═════╬═════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ 5 ║ 213 ║ 894,231     ║ ham,eggs         ║
╠═══╬═════╬═════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ 6 ║ 141 ║ 55,38,894   ║ tomato,onion,ham ║
╠═══╬═════╬═════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ 7 ║ 516 ║ 548,43      ║ milk,butter      ║
╚═══╩═════╩═════════════╩══════════════════╝
```

And I have **Table B**:

```
╔═══╦═════╦═════════════╗
║   ║  a  ║      b      ║
╠═══╬═════╬═════════════╣
║ 1 ║ ID  ║ LIST VALUES ║
╠═══╬═════╬═════════════╣
║ 2 ║ 231 ║ eggs        ║
╠═══╬═════╬═════════════╣
║ 3 ║ 518 ║ bacon       ║
╠═══╬═════╬═════════════╣
║ 4 ║ 732 ║ bread       ║
╠═══╬═════╬═════════════╣
║ 5 ║ 55  ║ tomato      ║
╠═══╬═════╬═════════════╣
║ 6 ║ 38  ║ onion       ║
╠═══╬═════╬═════════════╣
║ 7 ║ 894 ║ ham         ║
╠═══╬═════╬═════════════╣
║ 8 ║ 548 ║ milk        ║
╠═══╬═════╬═════════════╣
║ 9 ║ 43  ║ butter      ║
╚═══╩═════╩═════════════╝
```

These are representations of the data I have, and what I need help with. The actual data is a lot longer than these tables, and the delimited items can be very long.

What I'm trying to do is populate **Table A**, *Column C*. I need to search the items from **TABLE B**, *Column A* for the listed items in **TABLE A**, *Column B* within the cell through the whole range.

I guess this can be done vice versa as well. I am familiar with INDEX-MATCH function, but I'm not sure how to add searching within the cell.

Comment: Does your version of Excel support TEXTJOIN?

Comment: @BigBen Yes it does!

Comment: What about FILTER?

Comment: @BigBen I do not have that function

Answer (score 1):

Use `TEXTJOIN` and `ISNUMBER/SEARCH`:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(","&$G$2:$G$9&",",","&B2&",")),$H$2:$H$9,""))
```

[image]

Comment: I don't get any values with this function. Hold on, I'll get an image

Comment: Can you use Evaluate Function to step through? Are your IDs stored as numbers, or text?

Comment: http://imgur.com/gallery/e6cxCuH  the only thing that'll let me step in is the a3 is 123

Comment: Don't you want to look at `B3`, not `A3`? I think your formula is off.

Comment: When I change to B3, the table a, column b 141 (line 7) lists everything, an the rest is blank

Comment: I can't test this, but try confirming the formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Windows Excel, try:

```
C2: =TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,VLOOKUP(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(B2,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"),$G$2:$H$9,2,FALSE))
```

**Table A**

[image]

**Table B**

[image]

**Results**

[image]